# How can I turn the formatting marks off in Microsoft Word

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-word

How can I delete the '*right to left*' and '*left to right*' icons next to lines and sentences when using Microsoft Word. I believe I actually accidentally hit a couple of buttons which caused this, and I am unable to work on the document now.

Comment: Welcome to SU, Joyce! Can you explain what exactly you mean by the 'right to left' and left to right' icons ?

Answer (score 2):

I think i know what you mean, those are called "Formatting marks".
The button to toggle them on and off has this strange character on it, which you most likely are annoyed by in your document view as well (they do serve a purpose though):

[image: Formatting Marks Symbol]

For more details refer to this page from Microsoft:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/show-or-hide-formatting-marks-HA010102250.aspx